# Autograd's library stubs missing

Tags: deep-learning, conda, autograd

I installed [`autograd`](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) on an conda environment and when I try to import `autograd.numpy` it tells me that  "module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker..."

The puzzling part is that I'm able to run the same code on a similar Anaconda environment on a different computer.

I tried updating Anaconda and also force-reinstalled `autograd` to no avail.

What am I missing?

I'm using Spyder as my IDE.

Comment: can you include the output of `conda list` into your question? Also include the full error message